# Finding children classes of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

ive been trying to do some research but I cant seem to find the specific answer for this..

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="collapsingHeader">
    <div class="listItemWrapper">
        <div class="itemWrapper">
            <div class="itemImage"></div>
            <div class="itemLabel"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemWrapper">
            <div class="itemImage"></div>
            <div class="itemLabel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="collapsingHeader">
    <div class="listItemWrapper">        
        <div class="itemWrapper">
            <div class="itemImage"></div>
            <div class="itemLabel"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemWrapper">
            <div class="itemImage"></div>
            <div class="itemLabel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Now, as you can see, i have 2 `collapsingHeaders`, each with a `listItemWrapper`, which contains 2 `itemWrapper`, which each contain an image and a label.

I am using javascript to, when clicking on a 'collapsingHeader' class, to hide the .next element (which is the `listItemWrapper` container below it).

The problem I am having here, is that there is a slight bad animation when the `itemImage` collapses/hides with the container. So I am looking to further, when the `listItemWrapper` container is toggled to show/hide, to further target the 2 child `itemImage` classes and set their `display:none`.

So my thinking was something like, when the use clicks on a `collapsingHeader` class to..

`$(this).next().children('.itemImage')`

and then updating the css/class of each. But the above code isnt working as expected, and I think Im not using it correctly..

any ideas how to target certain child elements (deep) within a container div?

Thanks!

Comment: use `$(this).children('.itemImage').hide()`  or `$(this).find('.itemImage').hide()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below code  . to find children you don't need to use next(). use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find('.itemImage').hide();  

 or 

$(this).children('.itemImage').hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery `find()` you can find any element (based on type, class or id) within the `$(this)` element:

Simply change:

```
$(this).next().children('.itemImage')
```

to:

```
$(this).find('.itemImage').hide()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Friendly Crook, your answer is spot on right. :) Unfortunately could only mark 1 as the answer. >.<